# PHP: storing lines from a csv into arrays

Tags: php, arrays, excel, file, csv

The CSV file looks sort of like this:

```
user_id, fname, lname, country
001, cake, chocolate, US
002, ice cream, vanilla, US
003, pie, pumpkin, US
```

And I want to save each of these into an array like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => user_id [1] => fname [2] => lname [3] => country)
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 001 [1] => cake [2] => chocolate [3] => US)
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 002 [1] => ice cream [2] => vanilla [3] => US)
        [3] => Array ( [0] => 003 [1] => pie [2] => pumpkin [3] => US) 
)
```

Currently my code looks like this, but it only saves the last elem:

```
$file = fopen('csvexample.csv', 'r');
$i = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    //$line is an array of the csv elements
    $arr = array($i => $line);
    $i++;
}
fclose($file);
print_r($arr);
```

Please help! Not sure what I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

[str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
$arr = array_map('str_getcsv', file('csvexample.csv'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add to your array like this

```
$file = fopen('csvexample.csv', 'r');
$arr = [];  // init the array just for completness

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $arr[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Although this is not what you requested, I believe an associative array is more suitable. (Unless you have reason for said array format).

I explode the lines and use the first line as the keys which I later use array_combine with to make it an associative array.

```
$str ="user_id, fname, lname, country
001, cake, chocolate, US
002, ice cream, vanilla, US
003, pie, pumpkin, US";

$arr = explode("\n", $str); //explode on new line
$keys = explode(", ",array_splice($arr, 0,1)[0]); // get headers to $keys

//loop the array by reference with '&'
foreach($arr as &$sub){
    $sub = array_combine($keys, explode(", ", $sub)); // change the string into an associative array
}
unset($sub); //unset reference
var_dump($arr); //output
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(3) "001"
    ["fname"]=>
    string(4) "cake"
    ["lname"]=>
    string(9) "chocolate"
    ["country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(3) "002"
    ["fname"]=>
    string(9) "ice cream"
    ["lname"]=>
    string(7) "vanilla"
    ["country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(3) "003"
    ["fname"]=>
    string(3) "pie"
    ["lname"]=>
    string(7) "pumpkin"
    ["country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/354iT

---

Perhaps even better is to have the main array key be the user ID as in this example: https://3v4l.org/hMLil